# Delay based on item inside collection

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

i want to delay emit from observable based on item duration from inside array and print that duration value;id in subscribe ?

```
[{id:1000},{id:2000},{id:3000},{id:4000}]
                  .map(x => of(x).pipe(delay( x.id)) )            
                     .subscribe(x=>{ console.log (x.id)});
```

Comment: You could also use a [`delayWhen` operator](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/delayWhen/) for this

Comment: @kos , would u plz give syntax in my case with delaywhen

Comment: well, just as in the example I linked, just: `delayWhen(x => timer(x.id))`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're close... if you want to project each event into a new observable, then you need to use `mergeMap` as opposed to `map`.

```js
import { from, of } from 'rxjs'
import { delay, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

let events = [{id:1000}, {id:2000}, {id:3000}, {id:4000}]

from(events).pipe(
  mergeMap(event => of(event).pipe(
    delay(event.id),
  )),
).subscribe(event => { console.log(event.id) })
```

But note that `mergeMap` will run each event in parallel. For your very specific example, that would translate to each event being output with only 1 second of delay in between. The entire observable would complete in a total of 4 seconds.

If you want the delay to be the time *between* the events, then you would want to process each sequentially. You could look at `concatMap` for that:

```js
import { from, of } from 'rxjs'
import { delay, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

let events = [{id:1000}, {id:2000}, {id:3000}, {id:4000}]

from(events).pipe(
  concatMap(event => of(event).pipe(
    delay(event.id),
  )),
).subscribe(event => { console.log(event.id) })
```

Again for your very specific example, the above would be waiting one second longer each time in between the events. This observable would complete in a total of 10 seconds.

Comment: Wow all of your answers are so thorough. I'm reading all your answers and I think I'll finally understand rxjs haha.

Comment: @Noitidart Haha, thanks. ;-) I'm glad you're finding them helpful!

Comment: howcan i iterate through parent child like {id:1, child:[{},{}]

Comment: @user6069595 I'd recommend asking a new question, so you can get a more detailed answer. It's often difficult to convey code through comments. The quick answer would be to add something like `.map(event => event.child)` at the beginning of the process. There's also a shorthand operator called `pluck` that does that exactly. So you could also add `.pluck('child')` at the beginning.